# How do I use the Apache Commons Codec library from Clojure?

Tags: clojure, apache-commons

I'm trying to use the [Base 64 functions](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) present in the Apache Commons Codec package.  I'm using Leiningen, and have this in my `project.clj`:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
               [commons-codec/commons-codec "1.4"]]
```

Leiningen successfully finds the appropriate .jar.  I can't for the life of me figure out which class I actually need to import, though.  I have tried all variations of

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:import (org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64)))
```

but nothing seems to work.  What class name should I be using for this?

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are you including the downloaded .jar on your `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: Same as brian, creating a clean leiningen project with your settings works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. It looks like I was just calling the class itself incorrectly. The following worked fine after the `:import` line above: `(.decode (Base64.) s)`.  Thanks for the responses, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend cutting to the chase and checking where the rubber hits the road. Make sure Leiningen did in fact place the correct jar in the lib directory of your project. Open the jar and look inside and see of the class you are looking for is there. If the path to that class in the jar should match the path of your import statement.